Regular representation on group algebra mapped element into invertible matrix. Is the element invertible?
Suppose $K$ is a field and $G$ a group of order $n$. Then the group algebra $KG$ can be mapped to $M_{n}(K)$ - the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in $K$ - via the regular representation (we could order the group $G$ and use its elements as a basis). If an element $u$ of the group algebra is mapped to an invertible matrix $M$ can we conclude $u$ is invertible in $KG$? I think it should be true, at least for the semi-simple case, but I can't find any proof of it. Also, what changes if we replace $K$ by any ring $R$?
I tried to prove it by myself by analysis of the coefficients of the inverse of $M$, but I had no success and I do not believe that this should be a good way of trying to investigate it. Maybe some reference on representation theory would also be of some help, if anyone could provide it for me.
I think that decomposing the regular representation might help, but I couldn't find a way out yet.
Edit: another way of asking: if $v\mapsto L_v$ ($v$ an element of the group algebra and $L_v$ a matrix) and $L_v$ is invertible, is it true that the inverse of $L_v$ is the image of an element in the group algebra?

I think the easiest way is to show that your map $KG \to M_n(K)$ is an injective homomorphism of algebras.

@eti902 I don't see why it would help. I might be losing something simple but, for instance, there is the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$, wich is injective, almost every element in the image has a rational inverse but almost no integer has an integer inverse. Maybe I should use the fact that it is a morphism of algebras... but how could it help? Is the result true if we change $K$ by any ring?

The statement depends only on the multiplication, the addition is irrelevant. Hence we may formulate a more general version for monoids:
Let $M$ be a monoid. Then an element $a \in M$ is a unit if and only if the map $L_a:M \to M, x\mapsto ax$ is a bijection.
The easy direction is if $a$ is a unit. Let's prove the other direction. Suppose that $L_a$ is a bijection. From surjectivity, we get the existence of an element $b \in M$ such that $1=L_a(b)=ab$. By construction, this $b$ is a right inverse to $a$. To see that it also a left inverse, consider
$$L_a(ba)=a(ba)=(ab)a=1a=a=a1=L_a(1)$$
So that we conclude $ba=1$ from the injectivity of $L_a$.
This statement can be applied to the multiplicative monoid of every ring, for example to $M=(K[G],\cdot)$ and in this case it implies the fact about the regular representation that you're after. (Note that, by linear algebra, a matrix is invertible iff it defines a bijective endomorphism.)

I have the strong feeling that this is a duplicate.

I see... such an $L_a$ should be surjective. Now it looks obviuos. Great! It's a shame I didn't think of it. Thank you!

The inverse of a matrix is always a polynomial in said matrix. So the claim follows from the fact that $KG \to M_n(K)$ is injective.

Great! Thank you!

Remark: Looks like it maybe isn't true if we exchange $K$ by a ring $R$ that is not commutative though, since it looks like the inverse to be a polynomial on the original matrix only works for matrices over commutative rings, also in the other answer, surjectivity is true because $K$ is a field.
